# No clients available in SignalR Hub context

Tags: c#, signalr

I am new to SignalR and am experimenting with setting up a self host service that I can use to send events to other applications. I am having a problem getting a method to be called on all clients. In the code below _context.Clients.All is always empty. Any Ideas?

Test Method:

```
var server = new SignalRServer();
server.Start("http://localhost:8555");
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8555");
var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("testHub");
var executed = false;
proxy.On("testMethod", () =>
{
  executed = true;
});
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
var hub = new TestHubContext(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>());
hub.Test();
hubConnection.Stop();
server.Stop();
```

Self host server:

```
public class SignalRServer
{
    private IDisposable _signalR;

    public void Start(string url)
    {
        _signalR = WebApp.Start<SignalRStartup>(url);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _signalR.Dispose();
    }
}

public class SignalRStartup
{
    public static IAppBuilder App = null;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Hub:

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{

}

public class TestHubContext
{
    private IHubContext _context;


    public TestHubContext(IHubContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public void Test()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            // At this poing _context.Clients.All is always empty
            _context.Clients.All.testMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is empty? Are you looking at the All property? Does it say "No more information could be discovered" ?

Comment: Also what's actually happening? The method isn't being called but are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing @wdavo. Does that not work for signalR?

Comment: I'm not sure it not showing any information is a problem. My implementation works and it shows the same things yours does when you inspect the All property. Have you tried what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Have tried your answer and it works, so it must be something to do with the way the the All property is populated by SignalR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your context / client connections are fine. Without further information I'm guessing your problem is that you are closing your connection and server too quickly after calling hub.Test()

Comment out the two .Stop() calls (and stick a Console.ReadLine in there to keep the console open) and see what happens